# htaccess - Redirect old url to new url matching regex

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect old URLs from my site to new URLs for a custom forum (Permanent Redirect 301).

There are more than 10,000 pages in this case.

I can not do a RewriteRule for each existing page. Is there a way to perform a RewriteRule using a regular expression?

For example: I want to redirect an URL like http://www.myforum.com/topic/subject-1234-hello-world to http://www.myforum.com/subject/hello-world.

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/topic/subject-([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9-]+)$ /subject/$2 [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't work...

How should I have done?

Comment: Note : Tried RedirectPermanent too, instead of RewriteRule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to escape the hyphens.

You can try the below rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^topic/subject\-([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /subject/$2 [R,L]
```